# How to Create a Public Boolean in Java?

Tags: java, boolean

This is my first time asking a question here, so I'll ask you to bear with me: I am trying to create a public boolean method, isEven(), that will check if a number is evenly divisible by two and return a value of true or false based on that. However, as this is a public method, I am unsure of how exactly to write it; this is my process thus far:

```
public boolean isEven()
    {
    if(WHAT_GOES_HERE? % 2 == 0)
        return true;

    else
        return false;
    }
```

I would appreciate some advice on how exactly to go about writing this method; thanks in advance!

Comment: `public boolean isEven(int number){
   return number%2==0;
}`

Comment: or in functional fashion - `Predicate<Integer> isEven = (number)-> number%2==0;`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be

```
public boolean isEven(int value){
    return value % 2 == 0;
}
```

Using an if/else statement to return or set variables to boolean values is almost always redundant. Since you can return the condition you put in the if/else itself, the if/else is not needed.